# How to get a {{geocodeArea: xxx }} query to work in python using overpy?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to find all pubs in a specific area using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and selecting the area with *geocodeArea*.

Testing the following query on [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) gives me the desired result:

```
{{geocodeArea:berlin}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  way["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  relation["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

But when I implement that query in python using [overpy](https://pypi.org/project/overpy/)...

```
import overpy

api = overpy.Overpass()

result = api.query("""
        {{geocodeArea:berlin}}->.searchArea;
        (
          node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
          way["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
          relation["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
        );
        out body;
        >;
        out skel qt;
    """)

print("Amenities in nodes: %d" % len(result.nodes))
print("Amenities in ways: %d" % len(result.ways))
```

... I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testOP.py", line 15, in <module>
    """)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/overpy/__init__.py", line 119, in query
    msgs=msgs
overpy.exception.OverpassBadRequest: Error: line 2: parse error: Unknown type "{" 
Error: line 2: parse error: An empty query is not allowed 
Error: line 2: parse error: ';' expected - '{' found.
```

I guess that the problem has to do with the double curly braces, but so far escaping them and other variations didn't help.

---

**Possible solution with Nominatim**

Thanks to @scai I know now, that with *{{geocodeArea:xxx}}* overpass turbo only makes a geocode request. I decided to implement that in my program by myself using [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import overpy

city_name = "berlin"

# Geocoding request via Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="city_compare")
geo_results = geolocator.geocode(city_name, exactly_one=False, limit=3)

# Searching for relation in result set
for r in geo_results:
    print(r.address, r.raw.get("osm_type"))
    if r.raw.get("osm_type") == "relation":
        city = r
        break

# Calculating area id
area_id = int(city.raw.get("osm_id")) + 3600000000

# Excecuting overpass call
api = overpy.Overpass()
result = api.query("""
    area(%s)->.searchArea;
    (
      node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
      way["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
      relation["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
    );
    out body;
    """ % area_id)

# Printing no. of pubs in nodes and ways
print("Amenities in nodes: %d" % len(result.nodes))
print("Amenities in ways: %d" % len(result.ways))
```

The code ...

1. Does a geocoding request to Nominatim
2. Searches for the first element in the results (max. 3) which is a relation
3. Adds 3600000000 to get the area id from the relation id

It's not a very clean solution and I wonder if it's possible to directly use the first result (which is mostly the city just as point) for my purposes. Hints are still welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{{geocodeArea: xxx }}` is a special feature of overpass turbo and not part of Overpass API. overpy uses Overpass API directly which means you can't use this keyword.

However `{{geocodeArea: xxx }}` just tells overpass turbo to perform a *geocoding request*, i.e. transform an address into a geographic location. You can do the same, e.g. by making a call to Nominatim, Photon or any other geocoder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @scai! I now added a Nominatim call via geopy in my and it's working. Only thing is that it's bid clumsy, cause it needs the right city relation in the first few results.

Comment: @rayon would you mind sharing your implementation of this? I'm trying to replicate the geocodeArea behavior in my code and I though I was successful but I've found some scenarios where it doesn't render the same result.

Comment: Hey @CristianoDalbem, the solution I ended up with is the code I added to the end of my question.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve similar results using the `area` filter instead of  `geocodeArea`. For your example:

```
area[name="Berlin"]->.searchArea;
(
  node["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  way["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
  relation["amenity"="pub"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This could work, but for other areas maybe you need to be more specific with the tags used in the `area` filter, more information in the [Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Selecting_areas_by_name) for Overpass